Bootstrap function returning NA
When I run this code:
library(MASS)
library(boot)
library(shiny)

mean_func <- function(data, indices) {
  mean_score <- mean(data[indices, "Score"])
  return(mean_score)
}
paintersnum <- painters[,1:4] #making sure that there are only numeric variables in the dataset
paintersnum
set.seed(123) 
boot_result <- boot(data = paintersnum, statistic = mean_func, R = 1000)

print(boot_result)

validate(boot_result)

sum(is.na(painters))

boot_ci <- boot.ci(boot_result, type = "bca")
print(boot_ci)

I get this warning:
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
Call:
boot(data = paintersnum, statistic = mean_func, R = 1000)
Bootstrap Statistics :
WARNING: All values of t1* are NA

Does anybody know why are all  the values NA?
I tried to run the code and I was expecting something along the lines of this:
Bootstrap Statistics :
    original   bias    std. error
t1*   1.5203 0.036974     0.21489


painters does not have a "Score" column.

What would you suggest if I want to analyse the dataset with bootstrapping?

Your approach looks fine, it's just that data[indices, "Score"] selects a non-existing column in your input.
